# Make httpheader Connection: Keep-Alive into lower-case "keep-alive"

Tags: c#, httprequest

What I tried it to add new header:

```
request.Headers.GetType().InvokeMember("ChangeInternal",
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
    Type.DefaultBinder, request.Headers, new object[] { "Connection", "keep-alive" }
);
```

Actually it adds `keep-alive` header into Connection but it doesn't replace old one. So I get `Connection: Keep-Alive,keep-alive`.

I tried experimenting with Reflection but didn't got anything working.

There is other similar questions about this but there was no solution.

Comment: Why are you calling this via reflection and not directly on the `request` object?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? According to the HTTP specification the headers should not be case sensitive.

Comment: Darin, while using normal browser it sends lower case keep-alive, and when using webrequests it sends upper case Keep-Alive. While checking website logs it can easly see this. So I want to have headers exactly as my for example firefox browser.

Comment: I used the following solution...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650236/how-to-send-lower-case-keep-alive-header-through-httpwebrequest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do the following:

```
request.Headers.Remove("Connection");
request.Headers.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
```

It's not neccessary to set these headers via reflection.
In the first place it's important to remove the old entry as an call to `Add` adds another value if the key already exists (the result you saw with comma separated values).

It'd be even better to use the HttpRequestHeader Enumeration instead of the header name as string:

```
request.Headers.Remove(HttpRequestHeader.Connection);
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Connection, "keep-alive");
```

## Edit:

My bad. There's an explicit `Connection` property on the request-object which must be used in that case:

```
request.Connection = "keep-alive";
```

FYI: There are some more headers that must be set via their explicit propertries. For a list refer to this page, section *remarks*: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.HttpWebRequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

## Edit2:

Well, looking at [the connection property's source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/HttpWebRequest.cs,47458a2001cdb11d), you can see that it restricts setting these values:

```
bool fKeepAlive = text.IndexOf("keep-alive") != -1;
bool fClose = text.IndexOf("close") != -1;
if (fKeepAlive || fClose)
{
    throw new ArgumentException(SR.GetString("net_connarg"), "value");
}
```

So you have 2 options:

1. Stick with the upper-case value (which I'd prefer) as anyway you have no *real* reason for it being lower-case (*"So I want to have headers exactly as my for example firefox browser."*). And as Darin Dimitrov already stated, headers shouldn't be case-sensitive anyway.
2. Extend your reflection-approach in that way, that you first remove the header an then set it again in lower-case.

Comment: This looks like good way to change upper cases into lower-cases but I get exception: 
System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=The 'Connection' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.
Parameter name: name
  Source=System
  ParamName=name
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.ThrowOnRestrictedHeader(String headerName)
       at System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.Remove(String name)
       at System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.Remove(HttpRequestHeader header)

Comment: I dont get it. Getting error.
  Message=Keep-Alive and Close may not be set using this property.

Thanks for your replies

Comment: Thanks for help and suggestions. Ill probably try to experiment more as I have some understanding now and if it wont work Ill keep on upper-sace value.

Comment: There is a **real** reason why you'd need to do this. Some hosts recently are rejecting requests where `keep-alive` is not all lowercase as 403 Forbidden. One is a rather large host. Yes, they are violating the spec. That doesn't change the fact that it is a real reason to need to do this.