# How to change the "Connection: Keep-Alive" header to lowercase "keep-alive" in C#

Tags: c#, http-headers, httpwebrequest

I am sending some requests to a host which keeps rejecting my requests because of the `Connection` header in my requests. I need to change it to lowercase. I have the exact same issue as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250722/make-httpheader-connection-keep-alive-into-lower-case-keep-alive?noredirect=1&lq=1) question. However, that question is 3 years old, so I was wondering if there is a solution to this problem now?

The answer there talks about using reflection to remove the header first before setting it again in lower-case. Can someone explain how do I achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/reflection

Comment: @user2864740 No. "Some common headers are considered restricted and are either exposed directly by the API (such as Content-Type) or protected by the system and cannot be changed." Unfortunately, `Connection` is one such header.

Answer (score 2):

Stop and read [this solution using reflection on `ChangeInternal`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30071784/2864740), which is probably a 'sufficient' level of reflection. When using it, do *not* set Connection via the property.

---

This reflection relies on implementation details of a particular run-time. **While such may 'Work' in Microsoft's .NET 4.x implementations, there is ZERO GUARANTEE it will work on .NET Core, Mono, etc..** (In actuality, it mostly likely won't work.)

"And let's never speak of this again.."

```
private static void SetHeaderRestriction(string name, bool restricted) {
    var hInfoPi = typeof(WebHeaderCollection)
        .GetField("HInfo", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
    var headerInfoTableType = hInfoPi.GetValue(null).GetType();
    var headerInfoHashPi = headerInfoTableType
        .GetField("HeaderHashTable", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
    // Internal cache singleton of header info / restriction data
    var headerInfoHash = (Hashtable)headerInfoHashPi.GetValue(null);
    var connectionHeaderInfo = headerInfoHash["Connection"];
    // IsRequestRestricted is 'readonly', but reflection can trump.
    // An alternative would be to [temporarily] replace the entry entirely.
    var restrictedPi = connectionHeaderInfo.GetType()
        .GetField("IsRequestRestricted", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    restrictedPi.SetValue(connectionHeaderInfo, restricted);
}

void Main()
{
    var wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");

    SetHeaderRestriction("Connection", false);
    wr.Headers["Connection"] = "keep-alive";
    SetHeaderRestriction("Connection", true);

    wr.Connection.Dump(); // "keep-alive"
    ((HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse()).StatusCode.Dump(); // OK
}
```

This code executes in LINQPad (which is where `Dump()` comes from) and .NET 4.7.1. YMMV.

Comment: I am using HTTPWebRequest class and setting the headers using the Headers property. With your code, I see "Connection: keep-alive, Keep-Alive" in Fiddler, despite not using the Connection property anywhere in my code.

Comment: Interesting. There must be something in the bowls of generating the request later *sigh*.

Comment: @Anon What happens if setting `wr.KeepAlive = false` *before* assigning the header value? The default of the property is true. The "Keep-Alive" part of the header is coming in later, but should not be added if 'disabled' via the property.

Comment: If I set `request.KeepAlive = false` before assigning the header value, I get `Connection: keep-alive, Close` in the request header.

Comment: @Anon Ahh, per https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/net/system/Net/HttpWebRequest.cs,38c5d9f27a438dcf `KeepAlive` must be *false* and `IsVersionHttp10` must be *true* or else "Keep-Alive" and/or "Close" will be added when preparing the request headers. However, that will also use "1.0" in the request elsewhere *yuck!!!* - what about using HttpClient? Is that more 'amendable'?

Comment: This is the best answer on the topic so far, the only issue is that the header will be set to keep-alive,Keep-Alive. It seems this may be done at the OS-level.