# How to get full control over http header?

Tags: c#, .net, http-headers, httpclient

How can I:

1. Make https request with field "Connection: keep-alive"? ATTENTION: not "Keep-Alive", but "keep-alive".
2. Place headers in my specific order?
3. Remove 443 from "GET line"?

What I got (checked by the Fiddler):

```
GET https://test.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Host: test.com:443
```

How I want:

```
GET https://test.com HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
Host: test.com:443
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
```

This is my code:

```
var client = new HttpClient();

var request = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    RequestUri = new Uri("https://test.com"),
    Headers =
    {
        { "Host", "test.com:443" },
        { "Connection", "keep-alive" },
        { "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br" }
    }
};

var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
```

Also I tried this:

```
request.Headers.Add("Connection", "keep-alive"); // 1
request.Headers.Connection.Add("keep-alive"); // 2
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive"); // 3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37005125/how-to-set-connection-keep-alive-header-in-lower-case-through-httpclient

Also, the rfc states the header content should be case insensitive, so anything requiring it to be lower case should probably have a bugfix filed against it. https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt

Comment: Thank you very much, but question about headers order still not answered. Also, I know about RFC (case and order not matter), but I need exactly like I said in question.

Comment: You should really go by the RFC if you have control of both applications. If not, I'd recommend filing a bug.